# How to handle keyword flags with default values in custom classes?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop, keyword-argument

I have custom classes which utilize many keyword flags, which can be of any data type.

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, main_arg, para1 = True, para2 = False, para3 = 2, para4 = 0):
        if para1 and para2:
            a = para3
        elif para1:
            a = para4
        #and so on
```

Since there are many many parameters and much more logic (and they are not nicely named para# like in this example), I decided to use **kwargs

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, main_arg, **extras):
        if extras["para1"] and extras["para2"]:
            a = extras["para3"]
        elif extras["para1"]:
            a = extras["para4"]
        #and so on
```

However, this requires the user of the `Example` class to input EVERY argument to extras, and therefore there are no default parameters. I got around this by doing a quick check within the `__init__` function and filling in the default parameters.

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, main_arg, **extras):

        extras_keys_true = ["para1"]
        extras_keys_false = ["para2"]
        extras_keys_zero = ["para4"]
        extras_keys_two = ["para3"]

        for key in extras_keys_true:
            if key not in extras:
                extras[key] = True

        for key in extras_keys_false:
            if key not in extras:
                extras[key] = False

        for key in extras_keys_zero:
            if key not in extras:
                extras[key] = 0

        for key in extras_keys_two:
            if key not in extras:
                extras[key] = 2

        if extras["para1"] and extras["para2"]:
            a = extras["para3"]
        elif extras["para1"]:
            a = extras["para4"]
        #and so on
```

This looks ugly and is inefficient, but works as long as I update the values I expect in `extra_keys_...` as well as add another check for every new default value I need.

My question is if there is a better way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do some kind of software design with logic and design patterns:

Simplifying logic may help: If the first case is the case, it is overwritten anyway here. You won't have it this way, but maybe logic can be simpler.

```
    if extras["para1"] and extras["para2"]:
        a = extras["para3"]
    elif extras["para1"]:
        a = extras["para4"]
```

Or you group the params in logical groups like nested dicts or json.

```
Example("x", {"kwargs1": {"kw":arg, ...}, "kwargs2":{}...})
```

Or, what may be best:
With inheritance and polymorphism you could divide up the logic and reuse common code like now. That's the main reason to use it.

```
class AbstractExample:
    def __init__(self, mainArgument, a=None, b="123", c="path|to|"):
        self.setup(a)
        self.do(b)
        self.save_at(c)

    def setup(self,a):
        self.a =

    def do(self, b):
        self.value = b(self.a)

    def save_at(path):
        with open (path) as something:
            something.save(self.value)              


class ExampleA(AbstractExample):
    def __init__(self, *args, extra_arg="special", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        print(extra_arg)

    def save_at(path):
        # not saving
        pass


class ExampleB(AbstractExample):
    def __init__(self, *args, anything_else="also_important", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        print(anything_else)

    def do(b):
        # do something that is special in for cases like this

    def save_at(path):
        # these methods override the base class behavior
        non_overloading_method_to_do_this()

    def non_overloading_method_to_do_this():
```

With multiple levels of inheritance you can divide up every case you need and you will see to do this it is much simpler to think and debug this, than the logic you did.
It will call the all the methods in **init** based on the object you instanciate:

```
a = ExampleA(..., extra_arg="special", ...)
b = ExampleB(..., anything_else="also_important", b="1""...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I thoroughly understand the problem but maybe you can get arround it by using the `get()` method of a dictionary. This method gives you the value of the supplied key if it is in the dictionary. If not, you can assign it a default value. The code could for instance look like that:

```
param = extras.get('key', True)
```

In that case if `'key'` is not in `extras`, `extras['key']` will automatically be set to `True`. You can do the same then for every parameter.